# cakephp controller level Authentication

Tags: cakephp, authentication, controller

I am doing a Tourism System in cakephp, I have two different kind of end-users, one is Admin and another is register users, so I need two different view for those users and also the registers users should not access the any controllers of the Admin module,

Now I don't know how to separate those two users.

Answer (score 2):

By the sounds of it what you're looking for is [Prefix Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) which should provide you with everything you need.

Your URL can be prefixed with by admin (if applicable for the user in question):

`http://example.com/admin/posts`

which is *routed* to (in the Posts controller):

```
public function admin_index(){
    ...
}
```

which renders the `app/View/Posts/admin_index.ctp` view.

I'm not going to say much more because the documentation is really quite thorough in this area. Please be aware that if you start introducing more than two levels of privilege (e.g. user, super-user, administrator) then prefix routing isn't really suitable. You need to take a look at [Access Control Lists](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html) instead which is also covered by the framework.

Comment: Thanq Sam, for your suggetion

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone I got an alternate way to solve this thread, that is configuring each of the controller. Just put the following code in the controller which you don't want to give the access

public function beforeFilter(){
if($this->Auth->user('role')=='regular')
{

```
        $this->Session->setFlash('You cannot access');<br>
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'index'));<br>
    }   
}
```

so if anyone login as a regular user, he/she will redirect to the user controller or any other that you wanna specify

Comment: Hi @AaminKhan, this is a great simple solution! It might be a good idea to move this logic into a component so you don't have to duplicate the code for each controller you use it in?